# items acquired per hour

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to figure out how many items are acquired per hour based on current elapsed time(in milliseconds) and current amount of items acquired. I know it's fairly simple, I'm just stumped.

So for example:

z = items/hr

x = current items

e = elapsed time in ms

What formula would I use with these variables?

Thanks

Comment: the relation between $x$ and $e$ is linear, and in an hour you have 3,600,000 ms

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, then $z=\frac{x}{e}$ is what you would start with but then you have to convert hours into milliseconds.

Note that 1 hour $=$ 1 hour $\times$ $\frac{60 \text{mins}}{1 \text{hour}} \times \frac{3600\text{seconds}}{60 \text{mins}} \times \frac{3600000 \text{milliseconds}}{3600 \text{seconds}}=3600000$ milliseconds.

So, it'd end up being $z=\frac{x}{\frac{e}{3600000}}=\frac{3600000x}{e}.$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you started with no items, you can divide $x$ by $e$ to get the rate in units of $\text{items}/\text{ms}$.  Then you multiply this by $1000\,\text{ms}/1\text{s}$ to get the rate in $\text{items}/\text{s}$, and so forth:

$$\text{rate} = \frac{x\,\text{items}}{e\,\text{ms}} \cdot \frac{1000\,\text{ms}}{1\, \text{s}} \cdot \frac{60\,\text{s}}{1\, \text{min}} \cdot \frac{60\,\text{min}}{1\, \text{hr}}.$$

The reason you can multiply by these things is that each of them is equal to 1 ($1000$ milliseconds in a second, and so forth.)  All of the units cancel except $\text{items}/\text{hr}$, which is what you want.